# How can I fix this Render problem in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am a newbie in android development and when I was making an app I got a render problem which was -

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)

**I only tried to navigate from the home page to the signup page. And that was only my code. But when I started debugging it I found that the problem is from the XML file.**

Please tell me how may I solve this problem?

Comment: HI. If you want to solve the problem and if you know the problem is inside `.XML` why don't edit your question and share it?

Comment: edit your post not your code.

Comment: Thanks, But the problem is solved

Comment: It was all because of button's xml

Comment: I have solved it now